# Initialize Array in Ember JS Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to Ember and I am currently working on 3.8 version of Ember. I just want an array to be initialize in component file and then to use the array in template file. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mistahenry suggesting initialize array in the init function like

```
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('foo', [{
      id: 0,
      name: "baz"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: "bazzz"
    }]);
  }
```

otherwise eslint throwing error with latest Ember 3.8.

on js side you can initialize like

```
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  foo: computed(function() {
    return [{id:0,name:"baz"},{id:1,name:"bazzz"}]
  }),
  ...
});
```

on template side just call your variable

```
{{#each foo as |item|}}
  {{item.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: `` error  Only string, number, symbol, boolean, null, undefined, and function are allowed as default properties  ember/avoid-leaking-state-in-ember-objects `` This is the error i am receiving when i try to initialize array

Comment: Can you produce your error with ember-twiddle? I guess you have upgraded your ember with new version and getting this error.

Comment: Yes i am using the latest version of ember js and ember cli. Previously I was getting the error now i compiled it again and my issue got resolved. Thank You So Much for your help.

Comment: The error is caused by a linting rule provided by `eslint-plugin-ember`. It should avoid leaking state between instances of a component. If you do it like suggested in the answer, each instance of the component will share the same array. That might not be an issue if it's static but it gets weird as soon as you add or remove items from that array. This is fixed mid-term by class field but for the time being you shouldn't use arrays and objects as values in an `EmberObject.extend({})`. Wrapping them in a `computed` is easiest work-a-round and established practice: `computed(() => ['bar])`

Comment: @A.KursatUZUN I think you should edit your answer. What you are suggesting will result in a linting error for anyone using the latest ember. Either use a computed as `jelhan` suggested, or use `init(){ this._super(...arguments); this.set('foo', [{id:0,name:"baz"},{id:1,name:"bazzz"}]);}` I personally prefer the init solution b/c the property isn't `computed` in the true sense

Answer (score 1):

The best way to initialize an array on an Ember Object (which a component is a subclass of) is to use the Ember `A` helper. This is a function that returns a new Mutable Array (which provides a lot of helpful methods on top of a regular `[]`.

New Syntax:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  myArray = A()
}
```

Older Syntax

```
export default Component.extend({
  myArray: A()
})
```

Why is this even an issue? Because when you define a component, you're defining a factory for that component. When it comes time to use it, ember returns a new instance of that component class. Arrays in javascript are mutable and are stored by reference, so when you update that array, then create a new component instance, the new value of the array is also updated.

See this article for more information: https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/09/18/ember-best-practices-avoid-leaking-state-into-factories

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [Ember.NativeArray](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.8/functions/@ember%2Farray/A) by using an `init` hook in you component/controller.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { A } from '@ember/array';

export default Component.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  classNames: ['pagination'],

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    if (!this.get('content')) {
      this.set('content', A());
      this.set('otherContent', A([1,2,3]));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Only string, number, symbol, boolean, null, undefined, and function are allowed as default properties. You can not directly initialize an [ ] in ember property. you should use `classNames: computed(function() { return ['pagination'] })`

Comment: Are you sure, did you check the link to OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION from my message???

Comment: You can have a look at eslint rule https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/avoid-leaking-state-in-components.md

Comment: It's strange that the core team don't know about this rule )

Comment: I hope they are correct. `Component elements` need not follow eslint-rules. For Eg: `tagName` `classNames` can be an `array` https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/customizing-a-components-element/

Comment: And last think... what is wrong in my first post and why you dislike it??

Comment: Initialising an array inside `init()` function is also to be avoided. Since init is called whenever you call Post.create(), each post instance will always get its own tags array. Alternatively, you could make tags a computed property. It won’t observe anything, but will be unique to each instance:

Reference : https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/09/18/ember-best-practices-avoid-leaking-state-into-factories

Comment: even though it's an old one, the rule is still followed. cool :)